# Fixating the horizontal major gridlines

Tags: reporting-services

Im looking for a way of fixating the horizontal major gridlines. I need them to be positioned at 70 and 30. I am thinking of removing the major gridlines entirely and just add two striplines together with two textboxes indicating the level on the Y axis but I would prefer to do it with gridlines :)

an exaple with red lines below - disregard the existing gridlines.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using two striplines.

[image]

[image]